# PowerPoint image with link on master slide

Tags: microsoft-powerpoint

I have an **image with a url link on a master slide** in PowerPoint.  The link works in slide master view, but in normal view, the link does not work.  Is there a way to get an image with a link in a master slide layout to be clickable when that layout is applied to a slide?

thanks,
- Mike

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My approach would be:

Insert a shape (as a button) add text to it and insert a hyperlink using the right-click. (Of course, you can stylize it so it does not look like a button)

The hyperlink will not work as you are editing the presentation, but will work when viewing it.

[image]

I think if you only paste the hyperlink on an element like the slide footer, the hyperlink is there but no object showing it.

Comment: Thanks for responding Rafael.  I think I can have what appears to be the clickable object be on the master slide, but on the regular slide, put a transparent box with a link over the element sitting on the master slide.  This transparent box creates a hot spot.  I'm trying to avoid doing this though.  I'd rather have the link functional from within the master slide.

Comment: The example I made is on the master slide. And it is functional.